# i am sending post request but its saying `GET method not allowed` in axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

i wanted to send post request but its saying `GET Method not allowed` everything is correct the url,proxy,payload as i can sucessfully send post request in python requests but not in axios i dont know why?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const url2 = "http://replicate.com/api/predictions";
const headers2 = {
    "Origin": "http://replicate.com"
};

const payload2 = {
    "input": {
        "width": 1024,
        "height": 1024,
        "prompt": 'cow',
        "refine": "expert_ensemble_refiner",
        "scheduler": "K_EULER",
        "lora_scale": 0.6,
        "num_outputs": 1,
        "guidance_scale": 7.5,
        "apply_watermark": false,
        "high_noise_frac": 1,
        "negative_prompt": '',
        "prompt_strength": 0.8,
        "num_inference_steps": 50
    },
    "is_training": false,
    "create_model": "0",
    "stream": false,
    "version": "39ed52f2a78e934b3ba6e2a89f5b1c712de7dfea535525255b1aa35c5565e08b"
};

const agent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: url2,
    headers: headers2,
    data: payload2,
    httpAgent: agent,
    timeout: 45000
})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Response received:");
        console.log(response.data); 
        console.log("Status code:", response.status);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error encountered:");
      console.log(error.response.data)
       
     
    });
console.log("POST request sent!");
```

i have tried to:
check the {payload,headers,proxy} and reverify it, and they are correct i think the problem is in axios part

Comment: Perhaps it's being 30x-redirected. Security often state POST requests are non-redirectable so most clients work around this by sending a GET request of the same URL sans the POST data payload.